# Sharepoint Web Page iFrame Border issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, sharepoint

I have set the iframe properties as

`frameborder="no"` or `frameborder="0"`

still I could not remove the left border in IE Browser, but its working Chrome & Firefox browsers.

How do I get rid of that border?

Answer (score 0):

Change your frameborder to frameBorder (Capital B)

```
<iframe src="myFrame" width="500" height="500" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

In IE, B must be capital in order to adjust the border